# VIM "!" and the Windows start command

Tags: windows, shell, vim

I have configured `<F5>` to use the Windows start command, but trying to use the command line option "/wait" confuses VIM so that the command is not found anymore.

Here my old mapping:

`noremap <F5>   :w<CR>:!start "%:p"<CR>`

I changed the mapping to:

`nnoremap <F5>  :w<CR>:!start /wait "%:p"<CR>`

Using the later cause the following error:

> E371: command not found

But why "command not found", the command is still "start", isn't it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW changing the first `<CR>` separating the commands to `<bar>` does not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Vim implement `:!start` command it-self since Vim must handle background command correctly. And it doesn't have `/wait` option. See `:help :!start`.

> Using "start" stops Vim switching to another screen, opening a new console,
>   or waiting for the program to complete; it indicates that you are running a
>   program that does not affect the files you are editing.  Programs begun
>   with :!start do not get passed Vim's open file handles, which means they do
>   not have to be closed before Vim.
>
> To avoid this special treatment, use ":! start".

```
:nnoremap <F5>  :w<CR>:! start /wait %:p<CR>
```

FYI: original start command doesn't require double-quote for argument.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate help!
It did help a lot and is so … simple!